# Concat operation on string and null keyword

Tags: java, string, null, concatenation

As per my understanding, when + operator is used with two string literals, concat method is invoked to produce the expected string.
Example - `String s = "A" + "B";`

When there is null in place of one literals as below then it is generating below output. 
I am confused here - why it is not throwing `NullPointerException`?

```
    String str = null + "B";
    System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

> nullB

Answer (score 6):

> why it is not throwing `NullPointerException`.

Because, string concatenation applies string conversion operation to the operand which is not of type `String`, which is `null` reference in this case. The string concatenation is converted to:

```
String str = new StringBuilder("null").append("B").toString();
```

which wouldn't throw a `NPE`.

From [JLS §5.1.11 - String Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> This reference value is then converted to type String by string conversion. 
>   [...]
>
> - If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the string `"null"` (four ASCII characters `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`).

Comment: Your code is not correct, regarding oracle documentation, new StringBuilder(null) with throw a NPE. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: @RamonBoza Ah! Mistyped it. fixed it now.

Comment: Also see [JLS §5.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1); the first sentence directly refers to 5.1.11.

Comment: @Downvoter Kindly take care of your downvote, as I've fixed the little mistake there.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are concatenating two strings, `str` is not null. When you use + for joining the two strings, it takes null to be a string too.